# How can I substitute value in aspx?

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox in 1 panel

Then in another panel I have

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPopUpInfo" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopupImpact" Width="1000px" style = "align-items:center; text-align: center; display:none;">

<a class="hoverIDcard" href="#" userID="12345">MyID</a>
```

How can I replace 12345 in the line above with the value in the textbox?
I tried:

```
<a class="hoverIDcard" href="#" userID=textbox.Text>MyID</a>
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Have a look at this article on how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Kindly post your code here @Tho

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use jquery to replace the `userID` property.

```
var tbValue = $('#<%= TextBox11.ClientID %>').val();
$('#hoverIDcard').attr('userID', tbValue);
```

The above sample uses the ID of the link, which was not present. So add `id="hoverIDcard"` to reference it in jquery.

```
<a class="hoverIDcard" id="hoverIDcard" href="#" userID="12345">MyID</a>
```